# View and upload objects to a private Amazon S3 bucket via specifc web site

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building a course marketplace using WordPress with Tutor LMS Plugin. People will need to pay to get courses access, so only clients can see the material they bought (videos and PDF files).

They cannot be showed to non-clients.

I'm storing all the files on Amazon S3 private bucket. The server is on Amazon EC2.

I also need to upload files to this bucket using my frontend.

What is the best solution? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance role for your EC2, giving it the required permissions to use your S3 bucket, on the backend you can use the AWS SDK to use that bucket, which in turn will have the permissions you set in the Instance role. When clients log in they will be able to access their required files and users not logged in will not have access to files. This you will need to implement on your code.

Another way is also to have a pre-signed URL generated for your clients, giving them temporary access to their files. The pre-signed URL expires after x amount of time, which the clients will need to have a new URL generated.

Signed URLs are always the best choice since you don't have to manage file streams for uploads and downloads from your application layer.

There is one more enhancement, we can use a CloudFront in front of S3 and use cloud front signed URLs to upload the content and cloud front signed URLs to download the content that will improve your performance and security posture since S3 is not publically accessible to anyone.